# escape Json Attribute Name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, attributes, escaping

NodeJs Lambda should return payload

{
"statusCode": 200,
"body": {
"Customer_Code": "CCode",
"c_type_/_customer_type": "Customer Type"
}
}

Note the "/" in the atrribute name

I cant get to escape this attribute name in Lambda

This works

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    event.ctype__customer_type = "Customer Type";
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event,
    };
    return response;
};
```

but not this one

`exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    event.c_type_\/_customer_type = "Customer Type";
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event,
    };
    return response;
};`

Any clues. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

why no use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) :

event["c_type_/_customer_type"]